# Sort two list with the elements in an increasing order

Tags: sorting, merge, scheme

The question requires me to Complete the Scheme function merge, which consumes two lists of sorted numbers (in an increasing order) and produces a list of numbers which consists of all the two consumed lists in sorted order.

For example,

```
(merge (list 1 4 5 9) (list -1 2 4)) => (list -1 1 2 4 4 5 9)
(merge (list 1 4 5 9) empty) => (list 1 4 5 9)
(merge empty (list 1 4 5 9)) => (list 1 4 5 9)
(merge empty empty) => empty
```

Thanks for helping out!!

Comment: This looks like "Please write my homework for me".

Comment: Please ask a specific question.

Answer (score 3):

Since this smells like homework, I won't write any code, but I will tell you that what are doing is part of the [merge sort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).  Remember these two things:

- In functional languages like Scheme, you are asking the question *what value do I need to produce* rather than *what do I need to do*
- In Scheme, you often write more than one procedure to accomplish a single task

If you remember these two things and figure out which part of merge sort you need to implement, it should become fairly easy to figure out.